# How can I load .obj files in the Soya3D engine?

Tags: soya3d

I recently found Soya3D, and I want to import .obj files, but it seems to only accept .data files.  How can I import .obj files into Soya3D?

Importing a .obj file named "house" produces this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "introduction.py", line 7, in 
>     model = soya.Model.get("house")
>    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/soya/**init**.py", line 259, in get
>     return klass._alls.get(filename) or klass._alls.setdefault(filename, klass.load(filename))
>    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/soya/**init**.py", line 268, in load
>     dirname  = klass._get_directory_for_loading_and_check_export(filename)
>    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/soya/**init**.py", line 194, in _get_directory_for_loading_and_check_export
>     dirname = klass._get_directory_for_loading(filename, ext)
>    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/soya/**init**.py", line 171, in _get_directory_for_loading
>     raise ValueError("Cannot find a %s named %s!" % (klass, filename))
>   ValueError: Cannot find a  named house!
>   * Soya3D * Quit...

Answer (score 2):

According to [the (yet-in) complete guide to Soya 3D](http://download.gna.org/soya/soya_guide.pdf), the only supported model formats are .blend files or its own custom format. I've found a couple places that said you can import .obj files by placing them in a certain directory, but I'm not sure if it's true, and at least it's not in the documentation.

So to use your files, I recommend importing them with Blender, saving as a .blend file, then importing that with Soya. Either that, or use a separate .obj parser. [This file](https://www.mail-archive.com/soya@oomadness.tuxfamily.org/msg00066.html) may work, or I'm sure you can write your own, since .obj files are pretty easy to parse.